# zip folder in windows using command line

Tags: java, windows, command

I am writing a program that needs to zip a file.
This will run over both linux and windows machines. It works just fine in Linux but I am not able to get anything done in windows. 
To send commands I am using the apache-net project. I've also tried using Runtime().exec
but it isn't working. 
Can somebody suggest something?

```
CommandLine cmdLine = new CommandLine("zip");
     cmdLine.addArgument("-r");
     cmdLine.addArgument("documents.zip");
     cmdLine.addArgument("documents");
     DefaultExecutor exec = new DefaultExecutor();
     ExecuteWatchdog dog = new ExecuteWatchdog(60*1000);
     exec.setWorkingDirectory(new File("."));
     exec.setWatchdog(dog);
    int check =-1;
    try {
        check = exec.execute(cmdLine);
    } catch (ExecuteException e) {

    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

Comment: can we have a look at your code

Comment: What zip program are you using in Windows?

Comment: When you post the code, please also post any error messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same code won't work in Windows.  Windows doesn't have a "zip" program the way that Linux does.  You will need to see if Windows 7 has a command line zip program (I don't think it does; see here: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-files/how-to-compress-a-folder-from-command-prompt/02f93b08-bebc-4c9d-b2bb-907a2184c8d5).  You will likely need to do two things

1. Make sure the user has a suitable 3rd party zip program
2. Do OS detection to execute the proper command.

Answer (score 6):

Java provides its own compression library in java.util.zip.* that supports the .zip format.  An example that zips a folder can be found [here](http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/io/ZipFolderExample.shtml).  Here's a quickie example that works on a single file.  The benefit of going with native Java is that it will work on multiple operating systems and is not dependent on having specific binaries installed.

```
  public static void zip(String origFileName) {
    try {
      String zipName=origFileName + ".zip";
      ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipName)));
      byte[] data = new byte[1000]; 
      BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(origFileName));
      int count;
      out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(origFileName));
      while((count = in.read(data,0,1000)) != -1) {  
        out.write(data, 0, count);
      }
      in.close();
      out.flush();
      out.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Comment: You probably want to use `origFileName` as the argument to `ZipEntry`, not `zipName`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inbuilt compact.exe to compress/uncompress in dos

It displays or alters the compression of files on NTFS partitions.

> COMPACT [/C | /U] [/S[:dir]] [/A] [/I] [/F] [/Q] [filename [...]]

/C Compresses the specified files. Directories will be marked so that files added afterward will be compressed.

/U  Uncompresses the specified files. Directories will be marked so that files added afterward will not be compressed.

/S  Performs the specified operation on files in the given directory and all subdirectories. Default "dir" is the current directory.

/A  Displays files with the hidden or system attributes. These files are omitted by default.

/I  Continues performing the specified operation even after errors have occurred. By default, COMPACT stops when an error is encountered.

/F  Forces the compress operation on all specified files, even those that are already compressed. Already-compressed files are skipped by default.

/Q  Reports only the most essential information.

filename    Specifies a pattern, file, or directory.

Used without parameters, COMPACT displays the compression state of the current directory and any files it contains. You may use multiple filenames and wildcards. You must put spaces between multiple parameters.

---

Examples

compact

Display all the files in the current directory and their compact status.

compact file.txt

Display the compact status of the file file.txt

compact file.txt /C

Compacts the file.txt file.